# I create a function for getting a 300 dim weighted representation of each text in a corpus. Using this function in parallel with pbapply fails. Why?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

This is what I have:

```
`cluster <- makeCluster(10)
clusterExport(cluster, c("un_tokens_simplified", "glove_840B_300_all", "sif"))
clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(matrixStats))

process_row <- function(i) {
  word_list <- un_tokens_simplified[[i]][un_tokens_simplified[[i]] %in% colnames(glove_840B_300_all)]
  new_glove <- matrix(NA, nrow = 300, ncol = length(word_list))
  new_sif <- c()
  for (j in seq_along(word_list)) {
    new_glove[,j] <- glove_840B_300_all[,which(colnames(glove_840B_300_all) == word_list[j])]
    if(word_list[j] %in% names(sif)) {
      new_sif[j] <- sif[names(sif) == word_list[j]]
    } else {
      new_sif[j] <- 1
    }
  }
  rowWeightedMeans(new_glove, w = new_sif)
}

 result <- pblapply(X = 1:nrow(final_data), FUN = process_row, cl = cluster)
```

`

The function works as intended if I use it separately with input like 1, 2, 5, 20 etc.
It ALSO works with lapply and even pblapply IF I dont use the cl argument.
If I use the cl argument, I get NaNs for everything in the result object.

Is defining the new objects within the function the issue? I am relatively new to programming so don't have much intuition for "good" coding practice.. Regards